# Hirb doesn't work at all in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, ruby-on-rails-3.2, hirb

I followed the tutorial on [hirb rdoc](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/doc/) but unfortunately, my rails console is not working at all.

I've already done `sudo gem install hirb`

and added hirb to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'hirb', '~>0.7.0'
```

Then I launched `bundle install`

And I get this result :

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
> require 'hirb'
=> false
> Hirb.enable
=> true
> Municipality.all
Municipality Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "municipalities".* FROM "municipalities" ORDER BY name asc
=> [#<Municipality id: 1, district_id: 6, name: "Ambalamanasy II", created_at: "2013-01-16 12:11:45", updated_at: "2013-01-16 12:11:45">,
...
# doesn't work
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: don't use sudo to install gems.

Comment: thanks for comment, how can i get "gem install" working without sudo ?

Comment: See Rails section of the post: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score 8):

If your using pry as your rails console... add this in your .pryrc file

```
require 'hirb'

Hirb.enable

old_print = Pry.config.print
Pry.config.print = proc do |output, value|
  Hirb::View.view_or_page_output(value) || old_print.call(output, value)
end
```

Comment: Great! How do I expand the column width?

Comment: @yoshdog this gives formatting in pager structure how can we change to tabular form ? Any help will be heartly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yoshdog's answer is outdated - it returns an error:

> output error: # NoMethodError: undefined method `pager' for nil:NilClass

You can fix this by using the [updated code from the docs](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#hirb):

```
begin
  require 'hirb'
rescue LoadError
  # Missing goodies, bummer
end

if defined? Hirb
  # Slightly dirty hack to fully support in-session Hirb.disable/enable toggling
  Hirb::View.instance_eval do
    def enable_output_method
      @output_method = true
      @old_print = Pry.config.print
      Pry.config.print = proc do |*args|
        Hirb::View.view_or_page_output(args[1]) || @old_print.call(*args)
      end
    end

    def disable_output_method
      Pry.config.print = @old_print
      @output_method = nil
    end
  end

  Hirb.enable
end
```

This will also allow you to enable/disable Hirb, which may come in handy.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. This works beautifully.

Comment: @TheChamp, this gives formatting in pager structure, how can we change to tabular form ? Any help will be heartily appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `pry` it's works for me

```
$ pwd
/Users/me/path/rails-app
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r--   1 ryosuke  staff       554 12 26 17:50 .pryrc
```

and

```
begin
  require 'hirb'
rescue LoadError
  # Missing goodies, bummer
end

if defined? Hirb
  # Slightly dirty hack to fully support in-session Hirb.disable/enable toggling
  Hirb::View.instance_eval do
    def enable_output_method
      @output_method = true
      @old_print = Pry.config.print
      Pry.config.print = proc do |*args|
        Hirb::View.view_or_page_output(args[1]) || @old_print.call(*args)
      end
    end

    def disable_output_method
      Pry.config.print = @old_print
      @output_method = nil
    end
  end

  Hirb.enable
end
```